# Stretch swf video to fit the player

Tags: winforms, flash, c#-4.0

This should be something that a quick google search should have resolved but thus far has not.
I have an embedded AxShockwaveFlash object that loads a specific swf file. The file responds to commands that are sent it via the CallFunction method on the AxShockwaveObject.

What properties do I need to set in the designer to make the .swf video stretch to fit the AxShockwavePlayer object?

As an example, what I am looking for is behavior similar to [this](http://www.aleosoft.com/flashtutorial_autofitexample.html), only in a C# WinForms application and part of the screen will be occupied by controls and components.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the Flash size via CallFunction, instead define the embed properties width and height.

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html

How do you embed the flash object in the HTML?

Comment: It's not in HTML. It's in C#. That link isn't my work, it's an example of the behavior I'm looking for. And I'm not looking to set the scale mode by the CallFunction method, I'm looking to set it by the properties in the designer.

Comment: I didn't know you can embed Flash in C# :).